# Python: filter list of list with another list

Tags: python, list, filter

i'm trying to filter a list, i want to extract from a list A (is a list of lists), the elements what matches they key index 0, with another list B what has a serie of values

like this

```
list_a = list(
  list(1, ...),
  list(5, ...),
  list(8, ...),
  list(14, ...)
)

list_b = list(5, 8)

return filter(lambda list_a: list_a[0] in list_b, list_a)
```

should return:

```
list(
    list(5, ...),
    list(8, ...)
)
```

How can i do this? Thanks!

Comment: Your solution works for me if I fix the constructors for the lists. (Hint: use `[5,8]` instead of `list(5,8)`)

Answer (score 42):

Use a list comprehension:

```
result = [x for x in list_a if x[0] in list_b]
```

For improved performance convert `list_b` to a set first.

As @kevin noted in comments something like `list(5,8)`(unless it's not a pseudo-code) is invalid and you'll get an error.

`list()` accepts only one item and that item should be iterable/iterator

Comment: A more generic approach is to intersect the two lists.

Comment: @rjurney If you mean by using sets, then depends, do you want to lose order or preserve it? And thanks for the useful downvote.

Comment: It's often worth using a set for list_b: `set_b=set(list_b); result = [x for x in list_a if x[0] in set_b]`, on account of faster lookups + deduping the list. And there's no impact to ordering

Answer (score 5):

You are actually very close.  Just do this:

```
list_a = list(
  list(1, ...),
  list(5, ...),
  list(8, ...),
  list(14, ...)
)

# Fix the syntax here
list_b = [5, 8]

return filter(lambda list_a: list_a[0] in list_b, list_a)
```

Comment: Your comment about making the function beforehand is mistaken: `filter(lambda list_a: ..., list_a)` would do exactly the same thing, since the `lambda` statement is evaluated down to a function value before being passed to `filter`.

Comment: @Dougal - Thank you.  I did that because, a while back, someone got on me saying it re-created the `lambda` each time.  I thought that sounded wrong, but assumed he knew more than me and thus went with his advice.  Shows what you get for not double-checking info...