# How to merge JSON array and an array

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I have 2 arrays as below:

array 1:

```
[
    {"name": "A", "class" : "1"},
    {"name": "B", "class" : "2"},
    {"name": "C", "class" : "3"}
]
```

array 2:

```
[ "A","B"]
```

I wanna merge 2 arrays, and my expected result:

```
[
    {"name": "A", "class" : "1"},
    {"name": "B", "class" : "2"}
]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

What I found so far:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: filter list of list with another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448469/python-filter-list-of-list-with-another-list)

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to JSON, unless you are getting these values as a string. Your first value is just a normal Python dictionary.

Comment: This isn't a merge; it's a filter. You want to select the `dicts` whose `name` value appears in list 2. JSON is irrelevant, except as the source of one or both lists; the filtering doesn't care how the lists get defined.

Comment: @chepner I took it as a "merge" in the SQL sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a `list` comprehension:

```
first = [
         {"name": "A", "class" : "1"},
         {"name": "B", "class" : "2"},
         {"name": "C", "class" : "3"}
]

second = ['A', 'B']

result = [d for d in first if d['name'] in second]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'A', 'class': '1'}, {'name': 'B', 'class': '2'}]
```

In the case raised in the comments:

```
from operator import itemgetter

first = [
         {"name": "A", "class" : "1"},
         {"name": "B", "class" : "2"},
         {"name": "C", "class" : "3"}
]

second = [
         {"name": "A"},
         {"name": "B"}
]

result = [d for d in first if d['name'] in map(itemgetter('name'), second)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'A', 'class': '1'}, {'name': 'B', 'class': '2'}]
```

Comment: if the 2nd array is a JSON array : [{'name': 'A'}, {'name':'B'}]. How to achieve the result ?

Comment: @PhongVu `[d for d in first if d in second]` will work fine.

Comment: @PhongVu A JSON array is just a string that can be *decoded* into some native data structure. `[{'name': 'A'}, {'name':'B'}]` is an ordinary Python list consisting of `dicts` that was *initialized* from a JSON array.

Comment: Thanks @chepner for making clear the word "JSON array"

Comment: @gmds: I tried your suggestion, it just returns an empty array []

Comment: anyway, I marked it as an answer. My sub-question is just for learning

Comment: @gmds: Awesome. Thanks very much