# How can I exclude other matches to this regex?

Tags: list, python-3.7

The regex below (ip_regex) will find ALL IP addresses, but there is a long list of IP addresses that I do not want to match.  For example, I need to filter private IP addresses along with other public IP's.  How can I add to this regex to accomplish this?

```
    import re
    fh = "some file.txt"
    fh2 = "some file2.txt"
    ip_regex = re.compile(r"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})")
    
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip()
        match = ip_regex.findall(line)
        if match:
            for (ip) in match:
                print('\n'.join(match), file=fh2)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Just filter the results with your list of blacklisted IPs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you give me an example?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/TZ9Mv5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: filter list of list with another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448469/python-filter-list-of-list-with-another-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use the `ìp` variable to build an `IPAddress[1]` object. Then you could call `isPrivate()` method on it, or ask if it is contained in an `IPv4Network`. This would be a little more verbose, but a general regex which excludes random subnets would end in a less readable code.

In the modified snippet, I have also changed one line that seems like a bug to me (it is commented there).

```
import re
from ipaddress import IPv4Address
fh = 'ips.txt'
fh2= open ('filtereds.txt', 'w')
ip_regex = re.compile(r"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})")

with open (fh, "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines()
    for line in data:
        line = line.strip()
        match = ip_regex.findall(line)
        if match:
            for (ip) in match:
                ipaddress = IPv4Address(ip)
                if ipaddress.is_global: # and other criterias
                    # print('\n'.join(match), file=fh2) this would print all the line (with other IPs that does not fit criteria)
                    print(ip, file=fh2) #this would print only the matched IP
        else:
            pass
```