# filter python list based on values in a different list

Tags: python

I think this is an entry level computer science 101 course question about algorithms and data structures.

I have a list:

```
VAV_ID_list = ['36','38','21','29','31','25','9','13','14','19','30','8','26','6','34','11','12028','20','27','15','12032','23','16','24','37','39','12033','10']
```

How I can I filter out these values in `VAV_ID_exclude_list` from `VAV_ID_list`?

```
VAV_ID_exclude_list = ['36','38','21','29','31','25','9','13','14','19','30','8','26','6']
```

This code below obviously doesnt do anything any tips greatly appreciated.

```
filtered_VAV_ID_list = [zone for zone in VAV_ID_list if zone == 36]

print(filtered_VAV_ID_list)
```

Comment: ```list2= [zone for zone in VAV_ID_list if zone not in VAV_ID_exclude_list]```

Comment: Can you post your answer @Sujay? This works ill hit the green check box

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to keep elements of a list based on another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288403/how-to-keep-elements-of-a-list-based-on-another-list)

Comment: An "entry level computer science 101 course question" probably already has answers on Stack Overflow. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: This has been asked many times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: filter list of list with another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448469/python-filter-list-of-list-with-another-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want

```
list2= [zone for zone in VAV_ID_list if zone not in VAV_ID_exclude_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in multiple ways:

This is the most straightforward way.

```
>>> [i for i in VAV_ID_list if i not in VAV_ID_exclude_list]
['34', '11', '12028', '20', '27', '15', '12032', '23', '16', '24', '37', '39', '12033', '10']
```

You can even use sets if the order is not important and you don't have duplicates.

```
>>> list(set(VAV_ID_list) - set(VAV_ID_exclude_list))
['24', '11', '39', '27', '20', '23', '12033', '12032', '16', '37', '34', '15', '12028', '10']
```

Comment: Thanks for the info ill hit the 1 up arrow, but @Sujay answer first

Answer (score 0):

```
for el in VAV_ID_list:
    if el not in VAV_ID_exclude_list:
        print(el)
```

I think this will do it.